# Lebesgue measure of $\operatorname{Cl}A$ if $\operatorname{Int}A=\emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a boundary set ($\operatorname{Int}A=\emptyset$) and Lebesgue measure $0$   ($\lambda (A) = 0$). What can we say about Lebesgue measure of $\operatorname{Cl}A$ ?

It is obviously that we have $ \lambda \left( \operatorname{Cl}A \right) \ge 0$. But what we can say about the second inequality?

Comment: The rationals  have something to say...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\operatorname{Int}(\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1])=\varnothing$, though $\lambda(\operatorname{Cl}(\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]))=\lambda([0,1])=1$

Comment: So if $\operatorname{Int}A = \emptyset$ then $ \lambda (\operatorname{Cl}A) = \lambda(A)$ ?

Comment: No, this is not true even for my example. Look carefully!

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I don't have any idea how can me help yours answer. I understand what have you wrote, but I don't know how can I use it to find bounded of Lebesgue'a measure of set $A$. Could you give me next hint?

Comment: I do not understand thi sentence "how can I use it to find bounded of Lebesgue'a measure of set $A$"

Comment: I mean $\operatorname{Cl}A$. Because I would like find $a$ such that $\lambda(\operatorname{Cl}A) \le a$. I don't know how can I use your answer to get it $a$.

Comment: Consider $A=\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,a]$

Comment: Why I have to consider such $A$ as you wrote? What can I do with this set? Of course I see that Lebesgue measure of $\operatorname{Cl}A$ is $a$.

Comment: You asked me a set with empty interior and closure of measure $=a$. I gave an example. What else?

Comment: Yes but it is only example. As you can see I asked more general - $A$ is any set such that $\operatorname{Int}A= \emptyset$. We don't have more knowledge about $A$.

Comment: From my example we can say that the closure can have any measure.

Comment: Ahhh now i understand... Sorry for hassle and thanks for help!!

Comment: You are welcome!